# jQuery click to randomize number on string only triggered once

Tags: jquery

I need to randomize the number part of string on every click, hence 1 after sample should be randomized (**sample1**). I am concerned with the data-sample part, but showing the value as well to show the same click don't do any good. I suspect the number is just string on the following clicks.

JS fiddle [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/cLhSr/2/).

HTML:

```
<input id="input" value="sample1" data-sample="sample1"/>
<button id="button">Randomize</button>
```

JQUERY:

```
  var newRandomNumber = (Math.random()*10)+1;
  $("#button").click(function () {
    var value = Math.floor(newRandomNumber);
    $("#input").attr('data-sample', '').attr('data-sample', 'sample' + value).val('sample' + value);
    return false;
  });
```

Any hint is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The Math.random() is only called once in the declaration and initialization of var newRandomNumber. Every call to newRandomNumber is a call to the value, not to the assignment. That is why you only get it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the actual random number generation inside the click event. **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cLhSr/2/)**

```
  $("#button").click(function () {
    var newRandomNumber = (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    var value = Math.floor(newRandomNumber);
    $("#input").attr('data-sample', '').attr('data-sample', 'sample' + value).val('sample' + value);
    return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get a new random number on every click, not just on pageload, so place the random variable inside the click function :

```
$("#button").click(function(e) {
    e-preventDefault();
    var newRandomNumber = (Math.random()*10)+1,
        ran_value = 'sample' + Math.floor(newRandomNumber);
    $("#input").data('sample', ran_value).val(ran_value);
});
```